# Unit testing Realm on Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, realm

I'm trying to unit test my application which uses Realm for data caching, and am running into some problems.

1) I can't mock the Realm instance without using PowerMock. (PowerMock doesn't play nicely with my particular versions of Robolectric/Mockito, so I'd prefer not to use it). Is there any way to get around that short of Realm supporting an interface?

2) When working with RealmResults, is there a way to create one of these objects in a unit test? I can create RealmLists in unmanaged mode, but these can't be transformed into RealmResults. (Currently, my UI code expects to receive a RealmResults object containing the data - this is how we register listeners/etc)

Comment: Not it is not possible to mock Realm without Powermock, but perhaps it would be possible to hide Realm behind an interface.  Regarding RealmResults, then they implement the List interface, but right now there is no way of creating a manual RealmResults unfortunately.